# How to reduce redundancy in my json file for gulp-ng-config?

Tags: json, angularjs, gulp

I'm using `gulp-ng-config` to create a constants file for my angular project.

I have 5 different environments and currently have 7 constants.  However, the file structure is like this:

```
{
   "env1": {
      "EnvironmentConstants": {
         "param1": 1,
         "param2": 2,
         "param3": 3,
         "param4": 4,
         "param5": "env1"
      }
   }
   "env2": {
      "EnvironmentConstants": {
         "param1": 1,
         "param2": 2,
         "param3": 3,
         "param4": 4,
         "param5": "env2": {
      "EnvironmentConstants"
      }
   }
   "env3": {
      "EnvironmentConstants": {
         "param1": 1,
         "param2": 2,
         "param3": 3,
         "param4": 4,
         "param5": "env3"
      }
   }
   "env4": {
      "EnvironmentConstants": {
         "param1": 1,
         "param2": 2,
         "param3": 3,
         "param4": 4,
         "param5": "env4"
      }
   }
   "env5": {
      "EnvironmentConstants": {
         "param1": 1,
         "param2": 2,
         "param3": 3,
         "param4": 4,
         "param5": "env5": {
      "EnvironmentConstants"
      }
   }
}
```

As you can see in my example, all but the last param are identical.  How can I format this json file so that my gulp script gets all of the parameters without me having to duplicate a bunch of times.

Comment: Do you need to provide an actual `.json` file or could you use a node module via `require('somefile.js')` that would return json?

Comment: To answer @BrianGlaz Looking at the source it needs to be either a .json or .yml file. But in YAML they have the concept of default values, which would DRY up this data. I'm no expert w/YAML, so I'm stopping here.  Finally, I'd argue that if these values are all identical, they don't belong in this file at all and could be put into their own service.